# Toolbar text does not change in kivyMD and text goes beyond the boundaries

Tags: python, colors, toolbar, kivymd, textcolor

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    """This class manage the navigation drawer contents"""
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        """Return the main kivy file and set themes """

        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'BlueGray'
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Teal"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

MyApp().run()
```

and the kv file

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: dp("8")
        padding: dp("8")

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: "hexagon"
                    on_press:
                        root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                        root.screen_manager.current = "mainScreen"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'hexagon'

MDScreen:
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "Hexagon"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 9
        icon: 'account-circle'
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            MDScreen:
                name: "mainScreen"
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    size: root.width, root.height

                    ScrollView:
                        do_scroll_x: True
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        size_hint: (1, .85)
                        bar_width: 10
                        bar_color: (1, 0, 0 ,1)
                        scroll_type: ["bars", "content"]
                        pos_hint: {'top': 1.0 - toolbar.height/float(root.height)}

                        GridLayout:
                            id: labels_layout
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height:self.minimum_height
                            size_hint_x: None
                            width: self.minimum_width
                            cols: 1
                            spacing: "5dp"
                            padding: "5dp"
                            
                            MDLabel:
                                id: big_text_label
                                text: "asldklsa\nasdsaf\nssss\n"
                                width: self.texture_size[1]
                                height: self.texture_size[1]
                                
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

[test_screen_shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQoDP.png)

1. I want to change the color of the toolbar I tried almost everything to do it
   like **`md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color`** and **`md_bg_color: .2, .2, .2, 1`**
2. And the text goes beyond the boundaries even of the app if i add some widgets to get back
   text to its area the it goes under the toolbar

Using:
Python 3.9,  dev kivyMD 2.0, editor pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """ 
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: dp("8")
        padding: dp("8")

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                            
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    divider: None
                    text: "hexagon"
                    on_press:
                        app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                        #root.screen_manager.current = "mainScreen"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'account'
                        
##                BoxLayout:
##                    canvas.before:
##                        Color:
##                            rgba: [1,.3,0,1]
##                        Line:
##                            width: dp(1)
##                            rounded_rectangle:
##                                (self.x, self.y, self.width-dp(20), dp(43),\
##                                dp(12),dp(12),dp(12),dp(12),\
##                                dp(50))
                            
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    divider: None
                    text: "hexagon"
                    on_press:
                        app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                        #root.screen_manager.current = "mainScreen"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'hexagon'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    divider: None
                    text: "Edit"
                    on_press:
                        app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                        #root.screen_manager.current = "mainScreen"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'pencil'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    divider: None
                    text: "Home"
                    on_press:
                        app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                        #root.screen_manager.current = "mainScreen"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'home'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    divider: None
                    text: "Likes"
                    on_press:
                        app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                        #root.screen_manager.current = "mainScreen"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'star'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    divider: None
                    text: "hexagon"
                    on_press:
                        app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                        #root.screen_manager.current = "mainScreen"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'hexagon'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    divider: None
                    text: "Search"
                    on_press:
                        app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
                        #root.screen_manager.current = "mainScreen"
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'magnify'

Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        title: "Hexagon"
        md_bg_color: [1,0,0,1]
        specific_text_color: [1, 1, 1, 1]
        elevation: 0
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")]]
        right_action_items: [["account-circle", lambda x: print(222)]]


    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        MDScreen:
            name: "mainScreen"

            FloatLayout:
                BoxLayout:
                    id: m5
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .38} #this will change if you change this Window.size = (330, 500)
                    orientation: "vertical"
                
                    ScrollView:
                        do_scroll_x: False #True
                        do_scroll_y: True
                        #size_hint: (1, .85)
                        bar_width: 10
                        bar_color: (1, 0, 0 ,1)
                        scroll_type: ["bars", "content"]
                        pos_hint: {'top': 1.0 - toolbar.height/float(root.height)}

                        GridLayout:
                            id: labels_layout
                            size_hint_y: None
                            height:self.minimum_height
                            size_hint_x: 1
                            #width: self.minimum_width
                            cols: 1
                            spacing: "5dp"
                            padding: dp(20)
                            
                            MDLabel:
                                id: big_text_label
                                text: "\\n\\n\\n\\n\\n\\nWelcome to this New App.\\nYou will get a lot of benefits.\\n\\njbsidis recommendations are good so we can design in different ways."
                                
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                
                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    screen_manager: screen_manager

"""

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    """This class manage the navigation drawer contents"""
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    #nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()


class WeatherApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        pass
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen
WeatherApp().run()
```

Pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]